# First sets of LL(1) parser

Tags: ll-grammar

I have some problems understanding the following rules applied for first sets of LL(1) parser:

```
   b) Else X1 is a nonterminal, so add First(X1) - ε to First(u).  
    a. If X1 is a nullable nonterminal, i.e., X1 =>* ε,  add First(X2) -  ε to First(u). 
       Furthermore, if X2 can also go to ε, then add First(X3) - ε and so on, through all Xn until the first non­nullable symbol is encountered. 
    b. If X1X2...Xn =>* ε, add ε to the first set.
```

How at b) if X1 nonterminal it can't add ε to First(u)? So if I have

```
S-> A / a
A-> b / ε

F(A) = {b,ε}
F(S) = {b,ε,a}
```

it's not correct? Also the little points a and b are confusing.

Answer (score 0):

All it says is what are the terminals you can expect in a sentential form so that you can replace `S` by `AB` in the leftmost derivation. So, if `A` derives `ε` then in leftmost derivation you can replace `A` by `ε`. So now you depend upon `B` and say on. Consider this sample grammar:

```
S -> AB
A -> ε
B -> h
```

So, if there is a string with just one character/terminal `"h"` and you start verifying whether this string is valid by checking if there is any leftmost derivation deriving the string using the above grammar, then you can safely replace `S` by `AB` because `A` will derive `ε` and `B` will derive `h`.

Therefore, the language recognized by above grammar cannot have a null `ε` string. For having `ε` in the language, `B` should also derive `ε`. So now both the non-terminals `A` and `B` derive `ε`, therefore `S` derives `ε`.

That is, if there is some production `S->ABCD` and if all the non-terminals `A,B,C and D` derive `ε`, then only `S` can also derive `ε` and therefore `ε` will be in `FIRST(S)`.

The FIRST sets given by you are correct. I think you are confused since the production `S->A` has only one terminal `A` on rhs and this `A` derives `ε`. Now as per `b)`  `FIRST(S) = {FIRST(A) - ε, a,} = {b, a}` which is incorrect. Since rhs has only one terminal so there is this following possibility `S -> A -> ε` which specifies that `FIRST(S) has ε` or `S`   can derive a null string `ε`.